# Opening Phonegap ChildBrowser Plugin Window Just for Website Authentication?

Tags: javascript, iphone, cordova

I have a slight issue that someone might be able to point me in the 
right direction. As I'm a web guy but have little knowledge of 
objective c.

I am trying to retrieve some information from a website in javascript 
in my project that requires me to post login information to it (no 
problems there using Jquery $.post). The page I'm trying to return is 
only accessible after logging in (in a browser the site checks cookies 
and user-agents plus a bit of javascript leg work).

How can I create a hidden UIWebView that would do the login page 
(there for creating the correct session variables etc) so that I can 
retrieve the information I need?

Or is there a way I can get ChildBrowser Plugin to do this for me? If 
so how would I tell the Childbrowser window to close once it has 
reached the post-login page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up finding some type of solution.
http://www.pushittolive.com/post/1239874936/facebook-login-on-iphone-phonegap

Using that example I was able to set up childbrowser to open the login-action page, then detect the change and close the browser window.

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer if you no longer have an issue. Also, it may be worthwhile to summarize the linked article so the answer here is relatively complete.